# ¿Como puedo añadirle un temporizar a mi JFrame?

Tags: java, netbeans, timer

He intentado añadir un "temporizador" a mi JFrame, a temporizador me refiero a lo siguiente: quiero que mi JFrame se cierre después de usarlo durante cierto tiempo, ya sea un minuto, dos minutos, etc. Intenté añadir distintas funciones Timer pero no consigo que estas me funcionen. (Esta es mi primera vez en java, estoy usándolo desde NetBeans)

(ignorar: Esto es para que la pagina me deje publicar mi pregunta ya que dice que es mucho código, he buscado en varias páginas el cómo ingresar timers a JFrame pero al intentar hacerlo como lo dice en las páginas el código me lo marca como error, por lo tanto no sé qué es lo que está fallando o si lo estoy agregando o escribiendo mal)

Este es el código:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.Timer;


public class Ejemplo2 extends javax.swing.JFrame {
  Timer timer;

    public Ejemplo2() {
        initComponents();
        timer = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener() {
  @Override
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    updateTime();
  }

            private void updateTime() {
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); // Generated from nbfs://nbhost/SystemFileSystem/Templates/Classes/Code/GeneratedMethodBody
            }
        });
    }
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton3 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton4 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton5 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton6 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton7 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton8 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton9 = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jButton1.setText("1");
        jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jButton2.setText("5");
        jButton2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton2ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jButton3.setText("4");
        jButton3.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton3ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jButton4.setText("8");
        jButton4.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton4ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jButton5.setText("3");
        jButton5.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton5ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jButton6.setText("7");
        jButton6.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton6ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jButton7.setText("2");
        jButton7.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton7ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jButton8.setText("6");
        jButton8.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton8ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jButton9.setText("0");
        jButton9.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton9ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(62, 62, 62)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jButton6, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 50, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(jButton8, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 50, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(jButton9, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jButton7, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 50, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(jButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 50, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(jButton2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 50, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jButton3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 50, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(jButton4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 50, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(jButton5, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 50, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                .addContainerGap(267, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(77, 77, 77)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jButton7)
                    .addComponent(jButton1)
                    .addComponent(jButton2))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jButton3)
                    .addComponent(jButton4)
                    .addComponent(jButton5))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jButton6)
                    .addComponent(jButton8)
                    .addComponent(jButton9))
                .addContainerGap(155, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
if (jButton7.getText() =="0")
{
    jButton7.setText(jButton1.getText());
    jButton1.setText("0");
}
if (jButton2.getText() =="0")
{
    jButton2.setText(jButton1.getText());
    jButton1.setText("0");
}
if (jButton4.getText() =="0")
{
    jButton4.setText(jButton1.getText());
    jButton1.setText("0");
}
    }                                        

    private void jButton9ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
if (jButton5.getText() =="0")
{
    jButton5.setText(jButton9.getText());
    jButton9.setText("0");
}
if (jButton8.getText() =="0")
{
    jButton8.setText(jButton9.getText());
    jButton9.setText("0");
}
    }                                        

    private void jButton6ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
     if (jButton3.getText() =="0")
{
    jButton3.setText(jButton6.getText());
    jButton6.setText("0");
}
if (jButton8.getText() =="0")
{
    jButton8.setText(jButton6.getText());
    jButton6.setText("0");
}
    }                                        

    private void jButton4ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
if (jButton1.getText() =="0")
{
    jButton1.setText(jButton4.getText());
    jButton4.setText("0");
}
if (jButton3.getText() =="0")
{
    jButton3.setText(jButton4.getText());
    jButton4.setText("0");
}
if (jButton8.getText() =="0")
{
    jButton8.setText(jButton4.getText());
    jButton4.setText("0");
}
if (jButton5.getText() =="0")
{
    jButton5.setText(jButton4.getText());
    jButton4.setText("0");
}
    }                                        

    private void jButton5ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
if (jButton9.getText() =="0")
{
    jButton9.setText(jButton5.getText());
    jButton5.setText("0");
}
if (jButton2.getText() =="0")
{
    jButton2.setText(jButton5.getText());
    jButton5.setText("0");
}
if (jButton4.getText() =="0")
{
    jButton4.setText(jButton5.getText());
    jButton5.setText("0");
}
    }                                        

    private void jButton8ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
if (jButton9.getText() =="0")
{
    jButton9.setText(jButton8.getText());
    jButton8.setText("0");
}
if (jButton6.getText() =="0")
{
    jButton6.setText(jButton8.getText());
    jButton8.setText("0");
}
if (jButton4.getText() =="0")
{
    jButton4.setText(jButton8.getText());
    jButton8.setText("0");
}
    }                                        

    private void jButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
if (jButton7.getText() =="0")
{
    jButton7.setText(jButton3.getText());
    jButton3.setText("0");
}
if (jButton6.getText() =="0")
{
    jButton6.setText(jButton3.getText());
    jButton3.setText("0");
}
if (jButton4.getText() =="0")
{
    jButton4.setText(jButton3.getText());
    jButton3.setText("0");
}
    }                                        

    private void jButton7ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
     if (jButton1.getText() =="0")
{
    jButton1.setText(jButton7.getText());
    jButton7.setText("0");
}
if (jButton3.getText() =="0")
{
    jButton3.setText(jButton7.getText());
    jButton7.setText("0");
}
    }                                        

    private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    if (jButton1.getText() =="0")
{
    jButton1.setText(jButton2.getText());
    jButton2.setText("0");
}
if (jButton5.getText() =="0")
{
    jButton5.setText(jButton2.getText());
    jButton2.setText("0");
}

    }                                        

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new Ejemplo2().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton3;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton4;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton5;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton6;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton7;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton8;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton9;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He creado una variable static, he iniciado el timer con start, y después dentro de updateTime lo he parado y setVisible a false:

```
Timer timer;

static PruebaTimer pruebaTimer = new PruebaTimer(); // nueva propiedad

public PruebaTimer() { // he cambiado la clase a PruebaTimer
    initComponents();
    timer = new Timer(10000, new ActionListener() { // 10 segundos
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            updateTime();
        }

        private void updateTime() {
            // throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); // Generated from nbfs://nbhost/SystemFileSystem/Templates/Classes/Code/GeneratedMethodBody
            System.out.println("Hello world");
            timer.stop(); // añadido
            pruebaTimer.setVisible(false); // añadido
        }
    });

    timer.start(); // he iniciado el timer
}
```

Espero que te ayude.